# About 'unit-address' in Linux devicetree

Tags: linux, terminology, device-tree

In [Linux devicetree specification v0.3](https://github.com/devicetree-org/devicetree-specification/releases/download/v0.3/devicetree-specification-v0.3.pdf), p. 8, there is one sentence:

> The unit-address must match the first address specified in the reg
> property of the node. If the node has no reg property, the
> @unit-address **must be omitted** and the node-name alone differentiates
> the node from other nodes at the same level in the tree.

Here, what does *omitted* mean? Totally delete them? Simply write cpu@0 and cpu@1 both to "cpu"? Then how we differentiate them?